# Error while setting up Extjs Rest Proxy Create function

Tags: rest, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am using Rest proxy in Extjs Model as:

```
Ext.define('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model', fields: [
    { name: 'userId' },

    { name: 'title' },

    { name: 'body'}
],

proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    format: 'json',
    limitParam:"",
    filterParam: "",
    startParam:'',
    pageParam:'',
    url:'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',

    api: {
      read  : 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
      create: 'http://httpbin.org/post'},

    headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },     

    reader: {
    type: 'json',
    //rootProperty:'issues'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
```

In my view I am calling create function as:

```
var user = Ext.create('posts', {"userId": 124,"title": "sunt","body": "quia"}); 
user.save();
```

As I am testing everything on http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ so I am expecting that code will work cause when I test GET and POST functionality via Postman utility everything works fine.
Can anyone point out my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake.

In the following code I was not setting the correct name of my model, as it won't be "Posts"
    var user = Ext.create('posts', {"userId": 124,"title": "sunt","body": "quia"}); 
user.save();

Also if you are trying with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ you are not supposed to send ID in the post request.